# UICollectionViewを使用して、一定行毎に行間スペースを空けたい

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

## 環境

macOS High Sierra 10.13.5
Xcode9.4.1
Objective-C
iPad専用アプリを作成しています。

## やりたいこと

UICollectionViewを使用して1Section内にセルを200個表示しています。
以下のイメージのように2行毎にスペースを空けたいと思っています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayoutやUICollectionViewLayoutのサブクラス化あたりを使用すれば実現できるのかと思いましたが、良い方法が見つかりません。
(1Section内でこういった配置は不可能なのか...)

実現方法をご存知でしたらご教示いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`を使ってカスタイズできるパラメータはわずかで、それもセクションごとなので、`UICollectionViewFlowLayout`を使う限り実現するのは難しいでしょう。(そもそも`UICollectionView`は要素をセクションとアイテムと言う形で管理しており、(表示上の)「行」と言う概念はありません。)`UICollectionViewFlowLayout`のサブクラス化ではなく、大元の`UICollectionViewLayout`のサブクラスを直接定義した方が良いように思います。ただし、いろんなことをパラメータの設定だけで自動的にやってくれる`UICollectionViewFlowLayout`に比べるとハードルは一挙に3段階くらい上がる感じですが。私的には1セクションに200もの要素がダラダラと並ぶ、と言うトンデモUIを見直した方が良いように思います。

Comment: `UICollectionView`を使用する場合に行単位で何かを行うこと自体がナンセンスなのですね。なるほど。`UICollectionViewLayout`のサブクラス化も検討したいと思います。>`私的には1セクションに200もの要素がダラダラと並ぶ、と言うトンデモUIを見直した方が良いように思います。`これは1セクションに200要素は多すぎる! てことですか？大した数ではないと思っていたのですが問題あるのでしょうか？

Comment: 失礼しました。200ものアイテムが1セクションにずらずら並ぶのを「トンデモUI」と表現したのは、(Appleにリジェクトされる可能性があるとかの)問題ではなく、1ユーザとしての私の素直な感情です。初めから200もあることがわかっているのであれば、何らかの方法で絞り込めるようにした方がいいのではないかと。自分の意見が全iOSユーザを代表するなんてこれっぽっちも思ってはいませんが、ユーザ観点で評価してくれる方に相談くらいはしても良いのではと思います。

Comment: そうでしたか。今後、仕様検討をするにあたって参考にさせていただきます。ありがとうございます。

Comment: `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`と`UICollectionViewLayout`を勘違いしていましたので本文を修正しました

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionViewを１つのみを使った回答ではありませんが、私ならこのような方法を考えます。

まず、1つのセルのサイズが一定であるのであるのが前提です。
そうすると、2行分に入る要素の数(以下1ブロック要素数)が計算でわかると思います。
(今回の例であれば1ブロック要素数は22要素ですね)

その1ブロック要素数を内包する1つの大きなセルを作成し、それをUICollectionViewで縦に並べればできると思います。

1ブロック要素数を内包するUIはただのViewでも構わないでしょうし、UICollectionViewを使ってもいいと思います。

あまり美しくないかもしれませんが、今回の要件がマストであれば、一つの選択肢としていかがでしょうか？